# How can I make a nice and clean Variables storer? Having issue getting data through filters

Tags: c++

So I am doing my first "freestyle" project in c++.  I am sorta trying to build a opengl based engine.  I am trying to create a cpp that can store variables and structures... this way all other parts of the code can easily use the custom structures and acess and write to the variables (this is where a lives counter would go).

However I have noticed that while it compiles... the engine doesnt like me using my custom Coord3D structure in a .cpp that I have put lower in the filter (and included the Variables.cpp).

How can I get this so it is working properly?

Incase the images arent working....

```
Variables.cpp (located outside of the filters and folders)
using namespace std;
typedef float acc;//Defines the accuracy of the program

#include "Dependencies\glew\glew.h"
#include "Dependencies\freeglut\freeglut.h"
#include <iostream>

struct Config{
    bool Depth;
};
struct Coord3D{
    acc x;
    acc y;
    acc z;
};
struct Coord2D{
    acc x;
    acc y;
};
```

and

```
Shader_Loader.cpp (located inside of a folder/filter called "Core")
#pragma once
#include "../Variables.cpp"

Coord3D it;
it.x = 1;
it.y = 1;
it.z = 1;
//THe debugger likes to put red underlines under the last 3 lines under "it" however the program compiles....?
```

Comment: Eww. `#include "___.cpp"`

Comment: Have a header to declare that `struct Coords3D;`and include it where it needs to be used.

Comment: @NathanOliver ... whats wrong with it? I have the ../ so i can go up a filter and acess the largest folder.  Isnt that neccesary?

Comment: @Andrew you don't include .cpp's. You include .h's, which contain declarations for what you have defined in your .cpp's.

Comment: @TTavta pei (sorry for butchering your name) YOu mean that Variables.cpp needs to "#include" all of the .cpp's and .h's that will be using it aswell?

Comment: YOU * DON'T * INCLUDE * `.cpp` * FILES! Messes up any build system usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to members like this outside of a function body. You have to either assign to them in a function. It would look like this in a function

```
void myFunc()
{
    it.x = 1;
    it.y = 1;
    it.z = 1;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use uniform initialization. Change your `Coord3D` initialization to this:

```
Coord3D it{ 1, 1, 1 };
```

On another note, don't include `.cpp` files. Declare the structures and function declarations in a header (`.h` file) and include the header in your code files.